# JavaFx Cannot setItems on a ComboBox

Tags: java, javafx, combobox

I have a combobox and when I want to setItems, it gives nullpointerexception. I know what that means but I can't get why it returns null... Here is the code....

```
public void initialize(URL location, ResourceBundle resources) {
    ObservableList<String> list = FXCollections.observableArrayList("NA", "BR", "EUNE", "EUW",
            "LAN", "LAS", "OCE", "RU", "TR", "JP", "KR");
    region.setItems(list);
    region.getSelectionModel().selectFirst();
```

And here is the error...

> Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
>       at sample.summController.initialize(summController.java:76)
>       at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:2548)

Line 76 is the setItems one.
I check on javadocs and it seemed to be fine... Thanks for your help!

Comment: is `region` created before `initialize` is called? That's where I would start debugging, but you haven't posted a lot to work with.

Comment: Well region is created by fxml...I always declare them at the beginning of the class and use them in the initialize and it works...

Comment: Are you calling `initialize` before the scene is displayed, or after?

Comment: Well in javafx the scene is called in the main and this is a controller of a fxml. I set the root then it's displayed from the fxml, which is linked to a controller.

Comment: Obviously `region` is null. Can you post the declaration of `region` in the controller, the FXML file, and the code where you are loading the FXML file?

Comment: I don't have my computer right now but the way I do it is the folllowing: I set the fx:id for the combobox in scenebuilder, I set the controllee trought scenebuilder too and I write "@FXML private ComboBox region;" in the controller... Ill make sure it's done correctly tomorrow...

Comment: When you do, post the complete stack trace too.

Comment: Ok. I will do it.

Comment: On the same idea as James_D, if you created your node in FXML you need to make sure that the fxml fxid: is region. Also, You need to make sure you chose ComboBox and not ChoiceBox. Finally you need to make sure that you that you use @FXML private ComboBox region in the Controller. I sometimes mistakenly set my textField, promptText or a different node thinking that I have set the correct node's fxid.

Comment: fxml file: http://pastebin.com/9PzT6yZg Here is the declaration: @FXML
    private ComboBox region; And i'm loading it like that...: FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader(getClass().getResource("summ.fxml"));
                    Parent root1 = loader.load();